# Expressionengine multi language

Tags: multilingual, expressionengine

my final job on my current site is trying to add multi language capability to my EE site.

The steps I followed on the wiki here: http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Multi_language_site_alternative

were straight forward enough and despite having to search around for a bit of help when the htaccess didn’t work, I now have (I believe) a working subfolder on my site: /en . If i point my browser at http://mysite.com/en/template_group/view/title a page comes up fine.

The next step however of using en_custom_field doesn’t seem to work.
I have the feeling that the /en folder is an exact mirror image of the normal site.

For example in my embedded header template I have lang=”{country_code}” but when I view source in my /en subfolder it shows as “fr” (which is the default language)

Also, other curious things are happening - in the /en subfolder, my current dropdown menu (a navee menu) has been replaced by my old menu which is no longer in my template (!) I have literally no idea how this is happening…

Would appreciate any help from anyone who's seen something familiar thanks!

Comment: EE Insider published a recent article on [Multi-language Solutions for ExpressionEngine](http://eeinsider.com/articles/multi-language-solutions-for-expressionengine), which details many of the key multilingual fundamentals in one succinct article, complete with code examples and screenshots.

Comment: Thanks rjb, that's one of the articles I've already read on the subject. I now have the functionality up and running thanks by as usual, piecing together lots of different ideas. I'm currently stuck as I'm trying to put an if statement around my navee menu and it seems to be destroying my entire page... Removing code from before and after - strange!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ExpressionEngine 1.x or 2.x ? The instructions in the wiki really only work for 1.x (and not even very well for that).

There are several free and paid addons that can help you do this. For EE1, I'd recommend Transcribe: http://eeharbor.com/transcribe

For EE2, you might try Berkol's MultiLanguage addon, found here: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/multi-language-support -- it requires you to create custom fields, but handles all the URL nonsense pretty nicely as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks Adrienne, I'm on EE2. I actually started off using that addon but couldn't get it going and the wiki actually made more sense to me than the addon which was supposed to simplify matters! My latest problem is that the subfolder version is not finding the correct css